# HttpClient- adding parameters to Get request

Tags: c#, restsharp

I have a RestRequest which I am trying to convert to HttpClient Get request.  Is there any way I can send parameters the way it is done below?

```
private readonly IRestClient _restClient;
public Type GetInfo(string name)
{
    var request = new RestRequest(url, Method.GET);
    request.AddParameter("name", "ivar");
    var response = _restClient.ExecuteRequest(request);
    return ExecuteRequest<Type>(request);
}
```

Comment: There's no way to answer this question without knowing more about your implementation of `RestRequest`. These are not standard .NET types. If you're using a library, please identify it.

Comment: sorry, this is RestSharp

Comment: Can you clarify whether you are looking for custom HTTP headers or parameters on the request Uri (?name=value&name1=value1")

Comment: For a GET request you can either add them to the URL as query string parameters or to the http header as suggested by @ymz.

Answer (score 17):

If I recall correctly, RestSharp's `AddParameter` method doesn't add request headers but rather add Uri arguments for GET or request body parameters for POST.

There is no analogous method for `HttpClient` so you need to format the Uri for a GET request yourself.

Here's a method I find handy that will take a dictionary of string/object pairs and format a Uri query string.

```
public static string AsQueryString(this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> parameters)
{
    if (!parameters.Any())
        return "";

    var builder = new StringBuilder("?");

    var separator = "";
    foreach (var kvp in parameters.Where(kvp => kvp.Value != null))
    {
        builder.AppendFormat("{0}{1}={2}", separator, WebUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Key), WebUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Value.ToString()));

        separator = "&";
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the line where you are calling `Request.AddParameter(name, value)`, change that instead to `Request.AddQueryParameter(name, value)`.  For GETs this is the preferred approach and puts the parameters you specify into a querystring.